# In a letter, we may write "Attn. to: Mr. XYZ". What is the verb for "Attn. to"?

Tags: verbs

So if I want to write a letter which is "attention to" XYZ. Is there any verb for substitution?

Comment: Can you give an example sentence showing how you would use a verb.  Can you also tell us if the verb exists in your language and what a bilingual dictionary shows as a translation.

Comment: This is a letter's directive line, in which space is at a premium, so words are omitted to save space. This also happens in signage, instruction manuals, and newspaper headlines. This line will be understood to mean, "This letter **should come** to the attention of Mr XYZ."

Comment: At least in the UK, we often write "FAO Mr XYZ", being an abbreviation of "For the attention of" (not "to").  The implied words might be "This letter is"

Comment: Nope u don't have to. ----------
As Astralbee said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write a verb.

When you mark a letter "*For the attention of Mr Jones*", you are in effect saying:

> This letter is for the attention of Mr Jones.

So, the verb is "*is*" (the present tense third-person singular of "*to be*"). But you don't need to write it.

English grammar rules are not always observed in instructions, or commands. You can shout the verb "STOP!" without having to include any other words. You can write the adjective "TOXIC" on the side of a bottle as a warning. When you address a letter, all you need is a name and address - you don't write "Please can you deliver this letter to...".

Likewise, "for the attention of", or "FAO:" or "Attn:" are all abbreviated ways of marking a letter with an *instruction*. A verb is not required.